# File created not found Delphi and Android

Tags: android, delphi

I'm creating a file in a system folder, but then I can't find it anywhere. If I run the routine below again, `if not TFile.Exists(...` file will be located and loaded correctly. But if I try to find the `* .txt` physical file on the Android device, I can't find it anywhere.

Using this code below the file should be created in the directory:
**/data/data/com.embarcadero.MyApp/files/test.txt**. But I find neither the directory nor the `test.txt` file.

```
var lst: TStringList;
begin
   lst := TStringList.Create;
   lst.Clear;
   lst.Add('a');
   lst.Add('b');
   lst.Add('c');
   lst.Add('d');

   // This is the path: /data/data/com.embarcadero.MyApp/files/test.txt  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   if not TFile.Exists(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt')) then      
       lst.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt'));
```

Comment: You cannot find it. I believe so. But you did not tell how you searched for this for your app private file. Which tool/app did you use?

Comment: Ok, sorry... ES File Explorer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en

Comment: You placed the file in a for your app private directory. Private means no other app has access. So ES File Explorer has no access and cannot find it.

Comment: Ok. Is that wrong? Could you please advise me where should the file be created?

Comment: No it is not wrong. Its a save place. Its ok.

Comment: You call it a system folder but you use System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath. Look if System.IOUtils.tpath has other path members.

Comment: Thank you. Really very useful the TPath and with many options. Sorry for that question, but if in the future I need to find this physical file on the device, how do I do it?

Comment: You check if files exist with TFile.exists,(). And load it with TStringList.LoadFromFile().

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*if in the future I need to find this physical file on the device, how do I do it?*" - by putting it where it is *publically* accessible to all apps.  For instance, `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath` instead of `TPath.GetDocumentsPath`.